# Different result when processing Audio Interrupt for audio unit

Tags: ios5, audio, core-audio

I have searched all the related posts here and the Apple documents, without answers. By Apple's sample code "aurioTouch", I have a handler like this:

```
static void rioInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruption)
{
    printf("Session interrupted! --- %s ---", 
            inInterruption == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption ? 
            "Begin Interruption" : "End Interruption");

    AudioObjectImpl *THIS = (__bridge AudioObjectImpl *)inClientData;

    if (inInterruption == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {
       // make sure we are again the active session
        XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetActive(true), "couldn't set audio session active");
        XThrowIfError(AudioOutputUnitStart(THIS->rioUnit), "couldn't start unit");
        THIS->inInterrupt = false;
    }

    if (inInterruption == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {

       XThrowIfError(AudioOutputUnitStop(THIS->rioUnit), "couldn't stop unit");
        THIS->unitIsRunning = false;
        THIS->inInterrupt = true;
    }
}
```

AudioObjectImpl is the owner of the audio unit.
XThrowIfError(action, message) is a macro to execute 'action', and if it catches exception, print the 'message'. This is copied from the aurioTouch sample code.

This code did work for the incoming call interrupt, by rejecting the call, the interrupted audio is restored.
But it crashed when I choose a ring tone in the *"Settings|General|Sound|Ring"* .

The crash point is at ...AudioSessionSetActive(true)..., why it is different for these two cases? And how can it works in both cases ?